# Why didn't I earn another “Enlightened” badge?

Tags: support, badges

(Sorry for another complaint about a missing badge. I really seem to be dogged by bad luck in this respect.)

According to the "Badges" page, the requirement for earning an "Enlightened" badge (which can be awarded multiple times) is

> First answer was accepted with at
>   least 10 up votes

I have earned the "Enlightened" badge eight times so far. About 19 hours ago, [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076) to "Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles" -- the first and (so far) only answer -- had gained its 10th upvote and had become accepted. None of my other "Enlightened" answers had been downvoted to a score of below 10 or had their acceptance revoked, so according to the rules I should have earned a ninth "Enlightened" badge. This hasn't happened so far, though.

I'm aware of a potentially crucial facet: "Guidelines to customizing biblatex styles" is one of my own questions, so it was me who accepted my answer (after it had gained a score of +10). However, I rummaged through Meta.SO and didn't spot any rule or statement saying answers to own questions aren't eligible for the "Enlightened" badge.

I'd really like someone to shed light on this matter.

Comment: In the [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/155585) there's also no mention of self-accepting.

Comment: Now there is `:-)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Self-accepts are not eligible for this badge.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Am I correct to assume that self-accepts also don't count for the "Guru" badge?

Comment: By the way, my self-answered question revealed another small glitch: With my answer, my accept rate immediately dropped from 100% to 93% ("this user has accepted an answer for 14 of 15 eligible questions") although one cannot accept one's own answer for 24 hours.

Comment: @lockstep: You're wrong here. You can't accept your own answer for _48_ hours, but that's [from the time you originally asked your question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: @Hendrik: I stand corrected - about 72 hours had already passed when I answered my own question.

Comment: @jeff, is there a reason for this, or a post on MSO that details the rationale for this fact?

Answer (score 5):

Normally it takes a few hours until you get it. I get mine normally one hour after the connected *Nice Answer* bronze badge. The badge conditions are only checked in certain time intervals by the database. However, 20 hours seems long enough.

I would really say that self-accepted answers are excluded by the badge system to prevent abuse. Ok, you still need 10 other people to vote it up ...
I wouldn't be surprised if this rule isn't explicitly mentioned. Anyway, you might want to ask the question if badges are excluded from self-accepted answers in meta.SO.

Answer (score 4):

Corollary: Self-accepts are [not eligible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) for the [Guru](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/18/guru) badge.

Comment: I don't think any badges which require (an) answer(s) to be accepted will work with self-accepted ones.